# “private variable cannot be reduction” although that variable is defined outside the SIMD block

Tags: c++, openmp, llvm-clang

I have a C++ project which uses OpenMP, I try to compile that with LLVM on Blue Gene/Q. There is one function that, stripped down, looks like this:

```
template <typename FT, int veclen>
inline void xmyNorm2Spinor(FT *res,
                           FT *x,
                           FT *y,
                           double &n2res,
                           int n,
                           int n_cores,
                           int n_simt,
                           int n_blas_simt) {
#if defined(__GNUG__) && !defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)
    double norm2res __attribute__((aligned(QPHIX_LLC_CACHE_ALIGN))) = 0;
#else
    __declspec(align(QPHIX_LLC_CACHE_ALIGN)) double norm2res = 0;
#endif

#pragma omp parallel shared(norm_array)
    {
        // […]
        if (smtid < n_blas_simt) {
            // […]

            double lnorm = 0;

//#pragma prefetch x,y,res
//#pragma vector aligned(x,y,res)
#pragma omp simd aligned(res, x, y : veclen) reduction(+ : lnorm)
            for (int i = low; i < hi; i++) {
                res[i] = x[i] - y[i];
                double tmpd = (double)res[i];
                lnorm += (tmpd * tmpd);
            }
            // […]
        }
    }
    // […]
}
```

The error is this right here:

```
In file included from /homec/hbn28/hbn28e/Sources/qphix/tests/timeDslashNoQDP.cc:6:
In file included from /homec/hbn28/hbn28e/Sources/qphix/include/qphix/blas.h:8:
/homec/hbn28/hbn28e/Sources/qphix/include/qphix/blas_c.h:156:54: error: private variable cannot be reduction
#pragma omp simd aligned(res,x,y:veclen) reduction(+:lnorm)
                                                     ^
/homec/hbn28/hbn28e/Sources/qphix/include/qphix/blas_c.h:151:12: note: predetermined as private
                                double lnorm=0;
                                       ^
```

Due to the outer `omp parallel` block, the variable `lnorm` is defined for every thread. Then there is an additional SIMD section where each thread uses a SIMD lane. The reduction should be done within the thread, so the scope of the variables looks right. Still the compiler does not want it this way.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the **private** attribute attached to the `lnorm` variable by the `omp parallel` block conflicts with the requirements imposed by the OpenMP `reduction()` clause on its argument variable (even though `lnorm` **is not private** with respect to the nested `omp simd` block to which the `reduction()` clause applies).

You can try solving that problem by extracting the `lnorm` calculation code into a function of its own:

```
template <typename FT, int veclen>
inline double compute_res_and_lnorm(FT *res,
                           FT *x,
                           FT *y,
                           int low,
                           int hi)
{
    double lnorm = 0;

#pragma omp simd aligned(res, x, y : veclen) reduction(+ : lnorm)
    for (int i = low; i < hi; i++) {
        res[i] = x[i] - y[i];
        double tmpd = (double)res[i];
        lnorm += (tmpd * tmpd);
    }
    return lnorm;
}

template <typename FT, int veclen>
inline void xmyNorm2Spinor(FT *res,
                           FT *x,
                           FT *y,
                           double &n2res,
                           int n,
                           int n_cores,
                           int n_simt,
                           int n_blas_simt) {
#if defined(__GNUG__) && !defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)
    double norm2res __attribute__((aligned(QPHIX_LLC_CACHE_ALIGN))) = 0;
#else
    __declspec(align(QPHIX_LLC_CACHE_ALIGN)) double norm2res = 0;
#endif

#pragma omp parallel shared(norm_array)
    {
        // […]
        if (smtid < n_blas_simt) {
            // […]
            double lnorm = compute_res_and_lnorm(res, x, y, low, hi);
            // […]
        }
    }
    // […]
}
```